# Scrape from Craigslist

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping, pandas

I'm new to Python and just started to learn about scraping and pandas library. Here is a little scraper I wrote. I'd like to know what's a professional code for this would look like. I have a sense my code has a lot of redundancy but I don't know where to improve.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import requests


url = 'https://vancouver.craigslist.org/d/baby-kid-stuff/search/baa'
html_file = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(html_file.text, 'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())
postings = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'result-row')

locations = list()
prices = list()
names = list()

for posting in postings:
    location = posting.find('span', class_ = 'result-hood').text
    price = posting.find('span', class_ = 'result-price').text
    name = posting.find('h3', class_= 'result-heading').text.strip()
    locations.append(location)
    prices.append(price)
    names.append(name)

list_of_tuples = list(zip(locations,prices,names))
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns= ['locations', 'prices', 'names'])
print(df)
```

Comment: As a warning, craigslist is incredibly aggressive about blocking scrapers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't hard-code your URL - slice it up into parameters accepted by a function
- Omit the friendly `baby-kid-stuff`. There is a corresponding product category code, `baa`, that is more important to the requests and less redundant.
- Pass a [`parse_only`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) strainer to `BeautifulSoup`.
- Move your code out of the global namespace.
- Why are you using Pandas? Currently it seems to be just for printing; so don't use it at all; don't flatten your data. Keep it in well-typed structures.
- Consider supporting sortation criteria, a query string, an enumeration for known product codes, a "sub-area" code (e.g. `rch` for Richmond), parametric category codes, and including the item URL and timestamp in your results.
- Use a session to preserve cross-request cookies and set common headers.
- Set semi-realistic browser-like request headers and cookies.
- Use the response in a `with`, and check for failures via [`raise_for_status`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status).
- Do not leave your price as a string; make a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal).

### Suggested

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Iterable

from bs4 import SoupStrainer, BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session


class Sort(Enum):
    TIME_DESC = 'date'
    PRICE_ASC = 'priceasc'
    PRICE_DESC = 'pricedesc'
    RELEVANT_DESC = 'rel'


class Category(Enum):
    ALL_FOR_SALE = 'sss'
    FURNITURE = 'fua'
    HOUSEHOLD = 'hsa'
    GENERAL = 'foa'
    BABY_KIDS = 'baa'
    HEALTH_BEAUTY = 'haa'
    # etc.


RESULT_STRAIN = SoupStrainer('li', class_='result-row')


def search(
    session: Session,
    area: str,
    sub_area: Optional[str] = None,
    category: Category = Category.ALL_FOR_SALE,
    sort: Sort = Sort.TIME_DESC,
    query: Optional[str] = None,
) -> str:
    url = f'https://{area}.craigslist.org/search'
    if sub_area is not None:
        url += f'/{sub_area}'
    url += f'/{category.value}'

    params = {'sort': sort.value}
    if query is not None:
        params['query'] = query

    thumb_list = f'{Category.ALL_FOR_SALE.value}:pic'

    with session.get(
        url,
        params=params,
        cookies={
            'cl_def_hp': area,
            'cl_tocmode': thumb_list,
        },
        headers = {
            'Referer': f'https://{area}.craigslist.org/',
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return resp.text


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Result:
    url: str
    when: datetime
    title: str
    neighbourhood: str
    price: Decimal

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, html: str) -> Iterable['Result']:
        doc = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml', parse_only=RESULT_STRAIN)
        for item in doc.find_all('li', recursive=False):
            anchor = item.select_one('a.result-title')
            yield cls(
                url=anchor['href'],
                when=datetime.strptime(item.time['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                title=anchor.text,
                neighbourhood=item.select_one('span.result-hood').text,
                price=Decimal(item.select_one('span.result-price').text.removeprefix('$')),
            )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def print(self) -> None:
        print(
            f'{self.title}'
            f'\n{self.url}'
            f'\n{self.neighbourhood}'
            f'\n${self.price}'
            f'\n{self.when.strftime("%c")}'
            f'\n'
        )


def main():
    with Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) '
                'Gecko/20100101 '
                'Firefox/91.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml'
        }

        for item in Result.parse(search(
            session, area='vancouver', category=Category.BABY_KIDS,
        )):
            item.print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
Like new pricess pinky  rain boots with lining size: 2
https://vancouver.craigslist.org/bnc/bab/d/new-westminster-southwest-like-new/7363474417.html
 (New Westminster burnaby/newwest )
$20
Thu Sep  2 11:06:00 2021

# etc.
```